# Dynamic checkbox checked

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.11

I have a form. It displays for the user a checkbox list.
So the user can check any checkbox according to his choice.

This system is working.

However, I would like to indicate to the user what is the selection that he did before. The simpliest solution is to check every checkbox selected before.

For example, the first time I have to choose :[image]

And when my selection is good and if I go back to edit my choice, it could it be like that :[image]

So I can add another choice or remove any previous.

I hope it's clear and sorry for my english :)

forms.py :

```
class GamesRegisterForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_games_choices = []
    for game in Games.objects.all().order_by('title'):
        favorite_games_choices.append((game.guid, game.title), )    

    favorite_games = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        initial=True,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        choices=favorite_games_choices,
    )

class LogonForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        min_length=8, 
    )
```

models.py

```
class Games(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="GUID")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Titre")
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Logo")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class FavoriteGames(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey('Games')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want. When the form is saved and the user goes back to the form the changes should be saved and displayed. Please post your views.py (where you render the form)

Comment: Thanks to your help, I updated my explaination. I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `views.py` and include the user.  That way, you can query the database (through FavoriteGames) to select all games checked by the user (you already know because it's logged).

The result queryset can be passed as a context to bound the form so it reflects the user's previously chosen games.